# Caliburn Micro Action in ContextMenu with ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, caliburn.micro

I have a custom component with a ContextMenu in a ControlTemplate. I've read a couple of posts with people having trouble getting their actions to work in a ContextMenu. I've tried the workarounds posted there but I cannot get it to work. I keep getting `No target found for method Open.` None of these solutions used a ControlTemplate, however. I've tried to bind the model to the contextmenu, to the menuitems, to use TargetWithoutContext  property, but none seem to work.

```
 <components2:ImageBlock Background="Transparent" x:Name="ShareButton" Margin="0,0,7,0" >
     <components2:ImageBlock.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type components2:ImageBlock }">
               <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
               <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
               <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
               <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type components2:ImageBlock }">
                                <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MinHeight="30" ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}">
                                      <Grid.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                 <MenuItem Header="Facebook" cal:Message.Attach="Open(0)"/>
                                                 <MenuItem Header="Twitter"  cal:Message.Attach="Open(1)]" />
                                                 <MenuItem Header="Tumblr" cal:Message.Attach="Open(2)]" />
                                             </ContextMenu>
                                       </Grid.ContextMenu>
                                </Grid>
                         </ControlTemplate>
                     </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
           </Style>
      </components2:ImageBlock.Style>
  </components2:ImageBlock>
```

How can I get the Open to work at my viewmodel behind the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work through a `DependencyObject` that is added to the `ImageBlock`, where I had to set the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu` to the `ImageBlock`. Strangely, setting the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu` through `{Binding ...}` to `ImageBlock` directly didn't work.